# Finding difference of each items of array in efficient way

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to find difference of each items of 2 arrays.

```
int[] items1 = new int[] {10,20,30,40};
int[] items2 = new int[] {20,50,80,100};

resulting array should be
int[] resultItems = {10, 30, 50, 60 }
```

as the arrays are having more than 10K items, i am trying to avoid looping for better performance.
Is there a better way to handle this using LINQ to avoid performance issues?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How do you get 60 in the result set?

Comment: it's like....resultItems = Items2 - Items1 => {20-10, 50-20, 80-30, 100-40} = {10, 30, 50, 60}

Comment: Use simple loop. LINQ uses loop inside - no performance benefits.

Comment: Not sure there is a significantly faster way to do this than with a for loop. The code needs to go through both arrays and subtract one's elements from the other's. Within LINQ or within your own code, there will be a loop.

Comment: LINQ was not made for best performance. It was made for readability and maintainability and can so sometimes improve performance, cause you better read what happens. But for pure performance you still need for loops and threads.

Comment: What is your performance requirement. How big are your lists? Linq can easily handler millions of objects. And more over you can use .AsParallel to make Linq even faster at the cost of CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate over all the element in the array instead of using Linq, resulting in a linear time complexity - O(n).

Check the runtime for both the approaches, if efficiency is the only factor here, you might have to avoid linq.
Here is the runtime statistics on .Net Fiddle,

[Linq](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G4kwMe) Avg: 200ms [5 elements]

[For-loop](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FK82bi) Avg: 150ms [5 elements]

Here is the snippet,

```
        int variableSize = 10000;

        int[] items1 = new int[variableSize];
        int[] items2 = new int[variableSize];

        int[] resultArray = new int[variableSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < items1.Length; i++)
        {   
            resultArray[i] = items2[i] - items1[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple threads. Here's a quick sample of subtracting 10.000.000 integers on a single thread:

```
int []x = new int[100000000];
int []y = new int[100000000];
int []z = new int[100000000];

Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    x[i] = r.Next();
    y[i] = r.Next();
}

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// This code will be replaced
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    z[i] = y[i] - x[i];

stopWatch.Stop();

TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(ts);
```

This takes roughly 500 milliseconds on my hardware.

Now if I create this class:

```
public static class Subtractor
{
    public static void Subtract(int[] x, int[] y, int[]z, int from, int to)
    {
        for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
            z[i] = y[i] - x[i];
    }
}
```

and call it on 5 threads:

```
int []x = new int[100000000];
int []y = new int[100000000];
int []z = new int[100000000];

Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    x[i] = r.Next();
    y[i] = r.Next();
}

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// Use 5 threads instead of a single for loop
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Subtractor.Subtract(x, y, z, 0, 20000000));
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Subtractor.Subtract(x, y, z, 20000000, 40000000));
Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Subtractor.Subtract(x, y, z, 40000000, 60000000));
Task task4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Subtractor.Subtract(x, y, z, 60000000, 80000000));
Task task5 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Subtractor.Subtract(x, y, z, 80000000, 100000000));

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task5);

stopWatch.Stop();

TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(ts);
```

It only takes approx 150 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ nice and simple

```cs
var resultItems = items1.Zip(items2, (i1, i2) => i2 - i1).ToArray();
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eCjof5)

LINQ will not really be much different in performance than iterating the arrays simultaneously. A slightly more efficient implementation would pre-size a list.

```cs
var resultItems = new List<int>(items1.Length);
resultItems.AddRange(items1.Zip(items2, (i1, i2) => i2 - i1));
```

Comment: I tried both of these and, for some reason, they are both roughly 4 times slower on my hardware than using a single for loop on a single thread (2+ seconds vs ~500 ms). Not sure how LINQ works internally or if I did something wrong, but it appears that LINQ is considerably slower than using a normal for loop, at least when dealing with very large arrays (e.g. 10.000.000 elements)

Comment: True, but you need to get to really massive numbers for that to really make a difference. Yes there can be overhead, due to things like delegate invocation.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance try to use the [SIMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd) approach, e.g. via [System.Numerics.Vectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/)
The trick are CPU instructions which performs a single operation over a sequentially located chunk of data (usually 128/256 bits in size).

```
static int[] Difference(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    var N = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);
    var result = new int[N];
    
    var simdN = N / Vector<int>.Count * Vector<int>.Count;

    // processing the data by blocks via SIMD
    for (var i = 0; i < simdN; i += Vector<int>.Count)
    {
        var vA = new Vector<int>(a, i);
        var vB = new Vector<int>(b, i);
        var vResult = vB - vA;
        vResult.CopyTo(result, i);
    }

    // processing the rest of the data that is smaller than a SIMD register via a for loop
    for (var i = simdN; i < N; ++i)
        result[i] = b[i] - a[i];

    return result;
}
```

This code can be optimized via reusing `result` array.

If you're sure that your target CPU supports, e.g. AVX2, you can get a bit more performance with the [more specific](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/) `Vector256<int>` type.

```
static unsafe int[] Difference(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    var N = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);
    var result = new int[N];
    
    var simdN = N / Vector256<int>.Count * Vector256<int>.Count;
        
    fixed (int* aPtr = a)
    fixed (int* bPtr = b)
    fixed (int* cPtr = result)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < simdN; i += Vector256<int>.Count)
        {
            var vA = Avx.LoadVector256(aPtr + i);
            var vB = Avx.LoadVector256(bPtr + i);
            var vResult = Avx2.Subtract(vB, vA);
            Avx.Store(cPtr + i, vResult);
        }
    }

    for (var i = simdN; i < N; ++i)
        result[i] = b[i] - a[i];

    return result;
}
```

Here are my benchmark results for this approach with 100K elements. But your results may vary depending on the environment. So please measure before using any advice.

```
|    Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|---------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|
|   ForLoop |  65.57 us | 0.227 us | 0.212 us |
|    Vector |  16.91 us | 0.071 us | 0.066 us |
| Vector256 |   9.19 us | 0.049 us | 0.046 us |
```

Comment: This is just cool! Could you give more links to read about these features? Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

Using one of `Select`'s overload:

```cs
var diff = items1.Select((item1, index) => items2[index] - item1).ToArray();
```